# Disable keys and mouse click on iframe in Mozilla

Tags: php, javascript, firefox, iframe

I have applied this code for iframe id.

```
 <iframe id='<?php echo 'fraDisabled'.$i.$post->ID; ?>' src='<?php echo $file['url']; ?>'  ></iframe >


function disableContextMenu()
{

  var text="you dont have proper privelages to do this !!";
  window.frames['<?php echo 'fraDisabled'.$i.$post->ID; ?>'].document.oncontextmenu = function(){alert(text); return false;};
  window.frames['<?php echo 'fraDisabled'.$i.$post->ID; ?>'].document.onkeypress = function(){alert(text); return false;}; 
  window.frames['<?php echo 'fraDisabled'.$i.$post->ID; ?>'].document.onmousedown = function(){alert(text); return false;}; 
}
```

PHP:

```
<iframe id='<?php echo 'fraDisabled'.$i.$post->ID; ?>' src='<?php echo $file['url']; ?>'>
</iframe>
```

It works in Chrome but it is not working in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: I assume that "Mozilla" means Firefox.

Comment: You've got to escape the `'` in `var text`.

Comment: Are you sure this is exactly the code you have? I'd be surprised if any browser accepted it.

Comment: @juhana i actually passed php code , because iframe id is dynamic, i passed the php code with the loop.

Comment: And can you show how your iframes are added?

Comment: @zulfi you *still* have not given us the code that is generating the `<iframe>`. I have replicated the initial problem in FireFox, and my answer to include the `name` attribute fixed it in my testing... unless you give us everything, we **cannot help you**

Comment: i am unable to paste it in question, it is not visible there. the code for the iframe is this:-<iframe id='<?php echo 'fraDisabled'.$i.$post->ID; ?>' src='<?php echo $file['url']; ?>'  ></iframe >

Comment: When editing, did you put 4 spaces at the start of the line, as that will automatically turn it into a "code" block. Where is the `name` attribute I suggested putting in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably won't help that you have an apostrophe `'` in your text variable.

Change...

```
var text='sorry you don't have permission to do this !!';
```

To...

```
var text='sorry you don\'t have permission to do this !!';
```

Or...

```
var text="sorry you don't have permission to do this !!";
```

**ADDITIONAL**

You also need to change the `''id''` in the last 2 lines to just `'id'`

**UPDATE**

Looks like an issue with Firefox and the use of `windows.frames['id']` when the frame only has an id.

Try adding the dynamic id you're generating to **both** the `id` and `name` attributes on the `<iframe>`.

**YET ANOTHER PIECE OF INFORMATION HAS COME TO LIGHT**

I've just discovered that the `<iframe>` in question will contain a PDF document.

It would appear that Chrome will fire the click and context menu events as the OP is expecting... but IE and Firefox do not, which is more the behaviour I would expect.

Unfortunately I do not believe there is anything you can do about it.  And from a usability point of view, you are also making it impossible to scroll on the PDF using the scroll bar (mouse wheel would still work though).

I still believe that the `name` attribute is required in FireFox for the `window.frames` reference though.

Comment: Yes, @Veger, noticed that after my initial answer submission - already edited

Comment: @zulfi In that case, can you please copy&paste **into your question** *exactly* what the javascript you're using is

Comment: @freefaller now I edited the question, which i am exactly using.

Comment: Are you sure your iFrame's `id` is "id"?!  What your code is looking for is `<iframe id="id" ...>`

Comment: @freefaller actually I am using this in my php script, the id is dynamic, "<?php echo 'fraDisabled'.$i.$post->ID; ?>" which is working fine in google chrome, but it is not working in mozilla firefox.

Comment: @zulfi if the ID for the `<iframe>` is dynamic, how exactly to you think the javascript is going to be able to find it using `['id']`? You either need to get that dynamic id through to the javascript function somehow, or if there is only one single `<iframe>` (or `<frame>`) on the page, then just use `window.frames[0]`

Comment: for only asking the logic, i used "id" actually i passed the actual script which i mentioned in previous comment. there is a loop in my code which make <iframe>, i passed the id which is incremented with every loop, then i Use this javascript.

Comment: can you provide, any other logic to accomplish this task.

Comment: Apologies @zulfi, but it wasn't obvious that you'd replaced the names (you should have mentioned it)... please see my updated answer, as I was able to replicate your problem in Firefox

Comment: @zulfi - I'm not willing to spend much more time on this. Can you please edit your question to show **exactly** the code that is being generated, both the `<iframe>` and javascript.  Do **NOT** paste edited code, because that is not a true reflection of what is happening

Comment: i am unable to paste it in question, it is not visible there. the code for the iframe is this:-<iframe id='<?php echo 'fraDisabled'.$i.$post->ID; ?>' src='<?php echo $file['url']; ?>'  ></iframe >

Comment: Pdf files are dynamically posted, and i called them in Iframe to be viewed on that particular window,

Comment: @zulfi, why has it taken you *over an hour* to mention that the iframe is being pointed at a PDF file?!

Comment: @zulfi, I have updated my answer for the last time, I have already spent *way* too much time on this... good luck